# mysql replace unwanted symbols and characters

Tags: mysql, csv

I have a huge mysql database table. The table is like this (here I am just showing 5 rows)

```
id categories
1  !98!n!85!n!73!n!76!n
2  !110!n!29!n!76!n!75!n!81!n!80!n!37!n!42!n!1!n!150!
3  !73!n!80!n!81!n!75!n!76!n!110!n!29!n!37!n!42!n!1!n!127!n!30!n!84!n!6!n!150!n!126!n
4  !24!n!147!n!73!n
5  !59!n!97!n!73!n
```

Here you can see in the categories I have the data like 
`!98!n!85!n!73!n!76!n`. Now here you can see there is ! symbol before and after number , and there is n after the numbers. So I want to remove the unwanted datas and use comma in between two numbers. So the data will be like this

```
98,85,73,76
```

So can someone tell me how to do this in a smarter way. Any help and suggestions will be really helpful.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is the table defintion? How are the ids coming to table?

Comment: Normalize your data. This is going to cause you nightmares, if it hasn't already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute

```
UPDATE MyTable SET StringColumn = REPLACE(StringColumn, '!n!',',');
```

After That Execute

```
UPDATE MyTable SET StringColumn = REPLACE(StringColumn, '!n','');
```

After That Execute

```
UPDATE MyTable SET StringColumn = REPLACE(StringColumn, '!','');
```

May be this will help you